# Spring Integration ServiceActivator Method not invoking

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Migrating existing legacy application to java 11 and spring 5 and seems to be ServiceActivator method not invoking. I see publisher method invoking and printing log statement but no logs printing from ServiceActivator class

spring 5.3.14
spring-integration-* 5.5.7

XML Configuration:

```
<int:channel id="employeeServicesChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="employeeServicesExecutor" />
</int:channel>
<bean id="employeeServicesExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="40" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="10" />
    <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="0"></property>
</bean>
```

```java
 public class EmployeeServicesPublisher {

    @Publisher(channel = "employeeServicesChannel")
    public EmployeeServicesDto publishEmployeeServicesRequest(EmployeeServicesDto requestDto) {

        logger.info(" employee service request :" + requestDto);
        return requestDto;

    }
    
    
@MessageEndpoint
  public class EmployeeServicesServerGateway {

 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "employeeServicesChannel", outputChannel = 
                                                      "esDynamicOutputChannel")
    public EmployeeServicesDto processRequest(EmployeeServicesDto employeeServicesDto) {

        logger.info("===================================");
        logger.info(" request Id:" + employeeServicesDto.getRequestId());
        return employeeServicesDto;
    }
```

Comment: Before migration we have java 8 and spring 4.3.7

Comment: It's hard to say without much more information. Please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: Do you have an  `@EnableIntegration`? How do you check that log to be called? Since your `employeeServicesChannel` is an executor channel then processing for a published message happens on a different thread. Therefore you have to be sure in an async behavior of your solution.